# c++ member function thread safe

Tags: c++

I am writing a function for logging messages .
I will be calling this print function from different threads .
My code is as follows :

```
MyLog::printLog(const char* s)
    {

            std::string myline(s);
            //m_Mutex is class member and there will be only object for this class
            // shared by all threads
            int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&m_Mutex);
            if ( ret != 0 )
            {
                    std::cout<<" trying to lock same mutex char* "<<std::endl;

            }


            //code to log message in File

            pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_Mutex);
     }
```

My question is if above function is called from different threads with argument like "from thread1" , "from thread 2" ,... will there be any chance const char *s will be jumbled up  printing wrong values .?
I hope my question is clear .

Answer (score 3):

Your function will work as you expect, since `myline` is a local variable (each thread has its own stack, so would have its own instance of `myline`)

Comment: While this answer is correct, the reasoning is wrong. This is safe for reasons that have nothing to do with each thread having its own stack. For example, it would be equally safe for a single thread that called the function recursively even though the multiple instances of `myline` would be created on the same stack. The point is that each invocation of this function creates its own instance of `myline`. It has nothing to do with where those instances are created.

Comment: I mean that each local variable is different (it has a different memory location), and this is true both for recursive functions (locals are inside stacked call frames on the same thread stack) or for different threads (locals are inside different stacks). And there is no synchronization issues for a recursive function (only one call frame is active in each thread).

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling this function from different threads, and any changes you make to your argument `const char* s` are protected by your mutex `m_Mutex` then you'll be just fine and nothing will be jumbled.

**EDIT**

Actually, each call to this function will have it's own stack when called from a different thread, and seeing that it `const char*` you cannot change your argument, so there's no need to protect it with a mutex.

Your variable `s` is a variable local to the thread it's being called in, and it's `const`.

Then copying into the local variable `myline` is definitely not going to mess with anything, cause each thread has it's call stack, on which lives an instance of `myline` when this function is called, which is totally separate and independent of any other thread.

Comment: actually , my doubt was when printLog is called by thred1, const char *s will still point to a variable in stack which is perfectlly ok . But when second thread calls it and before storing it to local variable of first thread , isn't  there any chance 's' in thread one will point to local var in thread 2  causing jumbling ? i hope i am making sense

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, but the argument passed to the function is `const` and therefore you cannot change it, you have to copy it before making any changes, so there's no change of jumbling. The `std::string` you copy it into, copies the data, so then it's all thread local.

Comment: ok .. there is another function i am implementing as MyLog::printLog(char *s) as : { std::string myline(s); int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&m_Mutex); if ( ret != 0 ) { std::cout<<" trying to lock same mutex char* "<<std::endl; } //code to log message in File pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_Mutex); } In this case will there be problem ? As its char * not const char *?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are calling the `printLog` function. If the string whose address you pass to the function gets mutated by a different thread, then you may not see a consistent view of it inside the log function. If you pass in a pointer to an immutable string, like a literal for example, then you're fine, though.

Here's an example that's fine:

```
void from_thread_one()
{
    MyLog::printLog("Hello World");  // immutable string
}

void from_thread_two()
{
    MyLog::printLog("Another text");  // ditto
}
```

On the other hand, here's an example that's not OK and has a race:

```
char globalString[] = "This is a really long string";

void from_thread_one()
{
    globalString[5] = 'A';
    MyLog::printLog(globalString);
}

void from_thread_two()
{
    globalString[8] = 'Q';
    MyLog::printLog(globalString);
}
```

In this setting, you are making a copy of the string (via `std::string myline(s);`) while the contents of the array pointed to by `s` can simultaneously be changed in the other thread. In this scenario, dereferencing the char pointer has to happen inside the critical section as well.

The fundamental problem with your setup is that the raw char pointer has no implicit semantics that tell the user which behaviour is acceptable and which isn't. Had you passed in an actual `std::string` by value, you would have removed the uncertainty about synchronising access to the string from your `printLog` function and moved the responsibility entirely into the caller.

Comment: Got your point .. I am not calling it as shown in second way . I am using first way . So its thread safe .